# How do include a csv hyperlink, so that a csv file is downloaded when the hyperlink is clicked in the pdf?

Tags: csv, hyperlink

I want to have a hyperlink in my pdf which downloads a csv file to the users computer when clicked. How do I go about achieving this?

Please note, I would prefer it if the csv file was able to be downloaded from a file local to the pdf, rather than being a url to an online server, e.g. GitHub. Is this possible?

Comment: where is the csv in relation to the pdf?

Comment: You can use the `attachfile2` package, see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/attachfile2/attachfile2.pdf).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would prefer that the csv is contained locally (i.e. same folder), rather than being on a github server, etc.

Comment: simply `\href{file.csv}{csv}` should normally work, but not perhaps not in all pdf viewer. Embedding the file into the pdf is safer.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for this suggestion! I have read the package documentation, however I can't seem to make this work with Overleaf. Any further suggestions?

Comment: It does work with Overleaf too, of course you need to upload your `.csv` to your Overleaf project, then `\usepackage{attachfile2}` and in the document `\attachfile{myfile.csv}` produces an attachment icon in the pdf. The PDF reader in Overleaf itself cannot open this (that reader is somewhat limited and not intended for actual distribution of the document, just as a preview for yourself) but if you download the PDF from Overleaf and open it with your own pdf viewer then you will get the file.

Comment: Note that not all viewers have the same method for handling attached files, sometimes you just need to click the icon and you are asked to save or open the file, but in other viewers you need to right-click and select Save As or something similar.